# Access local resource to load values to observable collection in codebehind

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, data-binding

I want to fill a DataGrid with values of a ObservableCollection which is a property of a viewmodel class.

Unfortunately the following does not produce any results.

Page xaml:

```
<Page.Resources>
     <vm:vmProjects x:Key="Projects"/>
</Page.Resources>
<Grid>
    <DataGrid x:Name="dgProjects" AutoGenerateColumns="True"
     DataContext="{Binding Source=Projects}" ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList}">    
    </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
</Page>
```

Page Code:

```
vmProjects Projects;

public pgProjects()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    projects= (vmProjects )this.Resources["Projects"];
    LoadList(Projects.ProjectList); // this is a database layer, which fills the collection with value (works, there are items in the collection)

}
```

Comment: Does this work? `DataContext="{StaticResource Projects}"`. Either that, or set a new instance of Projects to the DataContext in the `pgProjects` constructor, and get rid of both the resource instance of `Projects`, and the DataContext attribute on the DataGrid.

Comment: It does! Thanks, that was very quick!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to do this:

First, since you're creating an instance of the viewmodel as a resource, your DataContext binding is wrong. That's very easy and quick to fix:

```
DataContext="{StaticResource Projects}"
```

But since your viewmodel seems to be a viewmodel for the whole page, this would simplify your life more in the long run:

```
<Page.DataContext>
    <vm:vmProjects />
</Page.DataContext>

<Grid>
    <DataGrid 
        x:Name="dgProjects" 
        AutoGenerateColumns="True"
        ItemsSource="{Binding ProjectList}">    
    </DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Now that same instance of `vmProjects` is the datacontext for the entire page, and you don't need to specify it for the DataGrid or any other child control.

To get to it in the code behind is simpler, too:

```
public pgProjects()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    LoadList(ViewModel.ProjectList);
}

public vmProjects ViewModel => (vmProjects)DataContext;
```